Unidentified plant with narrow leaf and white flowers
Does anyone know what this plant is? The leaves are long and narrow, and it has some white flowers in the middle.

Updates
Possible identification: Oldenlandia corymbosa L.
Here are some additional images taken during the daytime, but without strong sunlight. I also attempted using the iPhone's macro focus, but it did not yield satisfactory results.


where is the plant growing?  Outside in ???

@kevinskio It suddenly appeared in my flower pot and I live in HK country side.

BDW, picture of flower is not clear to us.

@Spectra thanks for your feedback, I have tried to add 2 more images and have found information on the web. See if it is correct. It seems like a kind of Herbs used in Chinese Medicine.
